# Establishing communication between laptop and an oscilloscope

Tags: usb, oscilloscope, communication, python

I am trying to establish a connection between [this](https://download.tek.com/datasheet/2SseriesMSO-Datasheet-48W738576.pdf) oscilloscope and my laptop using the USB port on the oscilloscope.

This is my code in Python:

```
    import time
    import csv
    import usb.core
    import usb.util
    #import libusb
    
    
    # Vendor and Product ID is obtained from the device datasheet.
    dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0699, idProduct=0x105)
    
    # Check whether the device is found.
    if dev is None:
        raise ValueError('Device is not found!')
    else:    
        print(dev) 
        dev.set_configuration()
```

I have installed every driver available and softwares on the website including IVI-COM driver and the shared components, OpenChoice_TekVisa_Deployment_Package_066093811 and OCD_2.6.0.14_066093914.exe . Still, the oscilloscope cannot be recognized. The USB port on the oscilloscope is USB 2.0 whereas I am using a USB Type-A to Type-C (on my laptop) to connect the two devices.

Do I have to buy a Type-A to Type-A male connector or should I do something else? I have enabled the USB port in the Utility menu within the oscilloscope.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What USB port are you plugging into on the scope? It sounds like you're using one of the USB A ports, which is wrong. You should be using the USB B port on the side. USB A is always used for the device controlling the link, and you want to control the link from the computer.

Comment: @Hearth There is no USB port in the front. There are two on the side of the scope. Is the USB A port only used to save to pen drives and such? Is it necessary to use the Type-B port to establish a connection with my laptop?

Comment: If you have USB Type-A receptacle, it is a USB host. Your PC is also a USB host. What cables or adapters you used?

Comment: @Justme I used a male Type-A to male Type-A connector between the two.

Comment: @Hearth So if I wish to control the scope, I should use the USB-A on my laptop and the Type-B port on the scope?

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull Yes. USB was designed to be unambiguous about which device is controlling the link, and I hate that USB C has made things ambiguous again.

Comment: This is also why type-A to type-A cables are not supposed to exist. The USB standard doesn't allow them.

Comment: Plugging in USB cables with the ends backwards like that is a great way to break your oscilloscope.  If you scope actually supports USB control, take a look in the manual and see how it should be connected.

Comment: @Hearth Slight exception, USB3 standard allows them to exist if VBUS is not connected between hosts. These "debug" cables should also be clearly marked as such, and they may have red connectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you used a cable with Type-A USB plugs on both ends.

Please do something with the cable so you never use it again.

Such cables should not exist, as they allow two hosts **and their power supplies** to be connected together.

Hope that your devices are not damaged now.

Only in recent times the USB3 specification has allowed such a cable, but only if it does not connect the power supply cable.

Older cables simply used these cables for normal USB operation because someone could not use the right connector when making millions of cheap products and so also millions of incompliant USB cables were also made.

Comment: So, can I use a type-A to type-C cable to connect the two?

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull Only if the type C end plugs into the oscilloscope.

Comment: @Hearth I find it difficult to decide which one is the host based on the cables... Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull Type A *always* plugs into the host. No exceptions. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Hearth Why is the more capable Type-C not associated with the host?

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull Type C can be a host or a device. Type A can only be a host. Type B can only be a device.

Comment: @Hearth One last question. What if it's a Type-C to Type-C cable?

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull The scope is a host, so is laptop. Scope can use USB memory sticks. Laptop can't look like a memory stick or pretend to be any kind of useful device to the scope as host.

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull Then the host and device will negotiate which one of them is the host and which is the device. Type C requires a lot more in the way of electronics on both ends of the link to handle this negotiation and other features of USB C; that increase in requirements is part of why USB A and B are still common.

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull You also can't use Type-C cables and adapters between USB host and laptop, and any adapters that allow you to connect them with Type-C cables are also forbidden by USB specs and should not exist.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of Tek oscilloscope has two different kinds of USB connector.  You need the "device port"; alternatively, consider using ethernet.

Quotes and image from [manual](https://download.tek.com/manual/2-Series-MSO_Help-077171603_RevA.pdf)

- **2: Device Port** "Use the USB Device port to connect to a PC to remotely control the oscilloscope using the USBTMC protocol"
- **4 Host Port** "Use the two USB Host ports to connect a USB memory device, keyboard, or mouse"

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I should be more careful from now on.

Comment: For my own work I tend to avoid USB and prefer ethernet, running data capture from whichever computer needs the data, not the one that's nearest the oscilloscope.